# JBAS014521: No message listener of type javax.jms.Queue found in resource adapter hornetq-ra

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, ejb-3.1, jboss-eap-6

I have added the following annotation in my MDB class:

```
@MessageDriven(
        name = "TestingXXXMDB", activationConfig = {
            @ActivationConfigProperty( propertyName="destinationType", propertyValue="javax.jms.Queue"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty( propertyName="destination", propertyValue="queue/Testing_XXX_QUEUE")
        }
    )
```

Error:

```
JBAS014521: No message listener of type javax.jms.Queue found in resource adapter hornetq-ra
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.EJBUtilities.createActivationSpecs(EJBUtilities.java:105)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.messagedriven.MessageDrivenComponentCreateService.createComponent(MessageDrivenComponentCreateService.java:98)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponentCreateService.start(BasicComponentCreateService.java:91)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.messagedriven.MessageDrivenComponentCreateService.start(MessageDrivenComponentCreateService.java:80)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 3 more
```

I am using JBoss EAP 6.3

Can anyone help me with this error and the solution to it?

Comment: On your destination type you have defined a Queue and your destination starts with topic ... strange.

Answer (score 1):

```
@MessageDriven(
        name = "TestingXXXMDB", activationConfig = {
            @ActivationConfigProperty( propertyName="destinationType", propertyValue="javax.jms.Queue"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty( propertyName="destination", propertyValue="queue/Testing_XXX_QUEUE")
        },
    messageListenerInterface = MessageListener.class
)
```

Try adding the definitive interface class to the annotation.